# Image Button Maxscript?

Tags: image, imagebutton, maxscript

Hey guys am trying to add an image to a button in 3dsmax/Maxscript, this is what i have so far and i am kinda stuck trying to figure it out,

```
try(DestroyDialog ShaderBalls)catch()
Rollout ShaderBalls "ShaderBalls" width:125 height: 70
(
    --Bitmap Local--
    button btn_rb  "RENDER"             map: C:\Users\kris.cabrera\Desktop\ButtonTest.bmp pos:[10,5] width:50 height: 50
    button btn_b   "NORENDER"         pos:[65,5] width:50 height: 50    
)
createDialog ShaderBalls
```

Comment: stop the try/catch stuff. That's just a bad habit from programmers who did this stuff 15 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create an image button:

```
    rollout image_button_test "Image Button"
(
button theButton "Press To Render!" width:200 height:200
on theButton pressed do
(
-- whatever you like for example, even turning your current renderview into the button image with the code below:

--theBmp = render outputsize:[200,200] vfb:off
--theButton.images = #(theBmp, undefined, 1,1,1,1,1 )
)
)
createDialog image_button_test 210 210
```